# What mode/scale are these notes in?

Tags: modes

I have created a short melody that uses these notes:

[image]

What mode contains these notes?

I have tried Dorian, Aeolian, Lydian, Phrygian and Mixolydian by starting at the scale in each mode that contains all naturals and working up via 5ths. But I can't find a scale that incorporates these notes

e.f. for Dorian, I started on D, then A, then E, etc. etc.

D  E  F G  A  B  C

A  B  C D  E  F# G

E  F# G A  B  C# D

B  C# D E  F# G# A

F# G# A B  C# D# E

C# D# E F# C# A# B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not any of the modes built on the Ionian scale but if B is your tonal center it is a part of the B harmonic or melodic minor scale.

Answer (score 2):

The modes you've tried — the "diatonic" modes — do not fit the notes you've composed. However, there are scales that incorporate them.

In particular both the B harmonic and melodic minor scales includes those pitches.

```
X: 1
T: B Harmonic Minor
M: none
K: none
L: 1/4
"_↑"B, "_↑"^C "_↑"D E "_↑"^F G "_↑"^A B ||
```

```
X: 1
T: B Melodic Minor
M: none
K: none
L: 1/4
"_↑"B, "_↑"^C "_↑"D E "_↑"^F ^G "_↑"^A B ||
```

The Musical Scale Search Tool lists a [number of other scales](https://www.scales-chords.com/fscale_res_en.php?rn1=A%23%2FBb&rn2=B&rn3=C%23%2FDb&rn4=D&rn5=F%23%2FGb&rn6=&rn7=&rn8=&rn9=&normal=1&greek=1&greekalt=1&other=1&etnic=1&c1=&t1=&c2=&t2=&c3=&t3=) that also include those pitches.

For example:

F♯ Double Harmonic

```
X: 1
T: F# Double Harmonic
M: none
K: none
L: 1/4
"_↑"^F G "_↑"^A "_↑"B "_↑"^c "_↑"d ^^e ^f ||
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you have used the notes A♯, B, C♯, D and F♯. The problem is that they won't belong to a diatonic *major* scale. The reason for that is that any key with an A♯ in it, will already have a D♯. And your tune has D♮.

We could look at those sharps as flats: B♭, C♭... - no, that's not going to help!

So, we look at minors, and that A♯ to B is a clue.It features in both the harmonic and melodic (rising) minors, where those two are the leading and tonic notes. Of B minor. The B minor scale goes B, C♯, D, E, F♯, G, A♯, B - or B, C♯,  D, E, F♯, G♯, A♯, B for the melodic. So, the key signature will be simply two sharps, as in B minor, and each subsequent A note will need a sharp before it. And B will most likely feel like 'home'. I hope there will be more of the tune than just five notes!

EDIT: just a thought, but if the A# was the anacrucis, putting more emphasis on the B at the start of the next bar, that would make it sound like it *is* in B minor. What do you think?

Comment: In the melody, B feels like the tonic and F# the fifth

Comment: So it's pointing more to being in key Bm. Unusual to start a melody on its leading note, on beat one.. Move the barline one beat to the right, and it seems to fit.